# ActionLink with simple URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My ActionLink reads as follows

@Html.ActionLink(image.FileName,image.FileLoc+"/"+image.FileName)

The image.FileLoc value is /content/3f1d6985-250d-45ff-abe6-dcab86437677
and image.FileName is mty2gm34.jpg

The corresponding href looks like this

```
<a href="/Images/content/3f1d6985-250d-45ff-abe6-dcab86437677/mty2gm34.jpg">
mty2gm34.jpg
</a>
```

Instead, what I would the href to look like is:

```
<a href="/content/3f1d6985-250d-45ff-abe6-dcab86437677/mty2gm34.jpg">
    mty2gm34.jpg
</a>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What are the values of your variables? What is the value of image.FileName? What about "image"? what about "FileLock"?

Comment: Have you tested this : `@Html.ActionLink(image.FileName,"/content/"+image.FileName)` ?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I updated my post with the values for image.FileLoc and image.FileName

Comment: Hi Sirwan, that did not work, it is including the original controller name /Images at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're linking a static resource instead of a controller action I'd forget about using `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` and use `UrlHelper.Content()`.

```
<a href="@Url.Content(image.FileLoc + "/" + image.FileName)">@image.FileName</a>
```